# SSH to servers with sudo access - script throws unexpected end of file error

Tags: ssh, sudo, for

I've to run a command `iptables --flush` in 100+ servers. I don't have root credentials, but have sudo access for my account. So I come up with a below script to run the command in all servers.

I added the servers names in the flushhosts file.

```
[root@~]# cat testscript.sh

> for i in `cat /flushhosts`
> 
> do
> 
> sshpass -p 'Mypwd' ssh -t username@$i sudo /sbin/iptables --flush
> 
> cat << EOF || "Mypwd"
> 
> done

[root@~]# ./testscript.sh

./testscript.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I couldn't find what I'm missing in the script.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the purpose of the line **cat<<EOF || "Mypwd"**?

Comment: I'm providing the sudo password for my account.
After executing the 'sudo /sbin/iptables' it will prompt for sudo pwd and so I've added that line.

Comment: this is in fact the problem, bash is expecting a `EOF` (the word EOF at begin of a line) to close `<< EOF` (this is called a here document)

Comment: I added "EOF" in a new line before done. Now looks like it's working.. Thank you.

Comment: You mean, there is no more a syntax error ? or sudo is takin Mypwd as password ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to a different approach I would like to propose using expect:

Create a small expect script **ex1.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh username@$arg1
expect "password: "
send "Mypwd\r"
expect "$ "
send "sudo /sbin/iptables --flush\r"
expect "password "
send "Mypwd\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Then you can use it in your loop like this:

```
for i in $(</flushhosts); do ./ex1 $i; done
```

You have a lot more flexibility with expect, for this kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

give try to

```
for i in $(</flushhosts)
do

   echo "Mypwd" | sshpass -p 'Mypwd' ssh -t username@$i sudo /sbin/iptables --flush

done
```

- this may work, but it is unclear `Mypwd` (in `echo Mypwd`) will make its way to sudo
- `$(</flushhosts)` is equivalent to `$(cat /flushhosts)` equiv to back quoted "cat /flushhosts "

about **cat << "EOF" || Mypwd**

1) cat << "EOF"

This will read lines until the word EOF is encountered, and whole text will be given to cat. this include the `done` word.

2) || Mypwd

if cat return non zero, then Mypwd (as a command) will be executed.

As no EOF word is found, when bash reach end of document, the `for ... do` is not close by a `done`, hence syntax error.

I expect this is not what you want.

the syntax

```
cat <<EOF 
hello world
EOF
```

is called a here document, this is a way to give data in shell script.